# Why do we need to call empty virtual method of parent class in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, virtual-functions

I am joining a legacy project in my company, an enterprise website developed with ASP.NET MVC.

As I am new to both C# and the framework (I'm from a Java background), I have failed understand this particular piece of code:

```
internal sealed class ValidatingModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        base.OnModelUpdated(controllerContext, bindingContext); // This is the damn call I'm stuck with

        var model = bindingContext.Model as IValidatableObject;
        if (model != null)
        {
            ValidateModel(model, bindingContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
    // more methods below...
}
```

Now, I was wondering what `base.OnModelUpdated(....)` call does, so I went ahead to the definition of `DefaultModelBinder`, only to find out `OnModelUpdated()` was a **virtual method** with **empty method body**:

```
protected virtual void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext);
```

What's the point of this? **Why is it making a call to an empty method of a parent class?**

Comment: It's merely showing you the definition, not the implementation. Note the `;` at the end. See [here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs#L544)

Comment: Hi @Rob I believe the point of calling a parent method is to have the data processed/consumed by the logic in the parent method. However in this particular case there is only a method definition (as you pointed out), and no concrete implementation. Then why bother calling it in the first place?

Comment: There's only the method definition available to you *to inspect*, but that doesn't mean there's no implementation. Much of the .NET stack was closed source (at least until recently). So while you may see what methods are available, you cannot see the source code inside the method. What you're seeing is simply the method definitions (ie, what the class allows you to do), but not how it does it. See my above link to the actual source code (depending on your version, it may slightly vary).

Comment: Thanks @Rob, that explains it well :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on how you went into the definition of `DefaultModelBinder`.
That class belongs to the .NET framework, and hence you need a decompiler (JustDecompile etc.) to look into the full source code (definition + implementation). This decompiler can be an external tool, or integrated into Visual Studio as Resharper etc. With those tools, when you navigate to the definition of the class, you can see the whole source code.

Otherwise, by default, Visual Studio will go into the file, which will pretty much just have empty definitions. (implementations may be missing)

The real definition of the file and method can be seen here:

https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs

As you can see, the implementation is not empty.

Also, note that calling into the base class' method is not mandatory. It is normally done, only to reuse the logic from the base class in terms of doing certain things 100% of the time, before you apply any concrete class specific logic.

Comment: damn, that was it! I right-clicked on the method and went to `Go To Definition`...and apparently that was not enough. It all makes sense now, thanks Raja!